# TorBrowserDriver.get function gets stuck after invoking the URL (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tor

I am using TorBrowserDriver to download a couple of files. After executing the first URL I am able to find the file in TorBrowser's download directory but the execution gets stuck at this point.

Following is my code,

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
import time
driver = TorBrowserDriver(PATH_OF_TOR_DRIVER)
for url in urls:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(DELAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except :
        print("error occured, closing the connection.")
        driver.close()
```

I have also tried some workarounds like func_timeout library to terminate the block if it stays for more than x seconds but still, the driver won't terminate and it occupies lots of ram due to lots of active drivers.

Also, I am a novice with TorBrowserDriver, so please excuse any of the mistakes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to terminate a browser instance, you need to use "driver.quit()". You are using "driver.close()" which only closes the windows but it doesn't kill the browser instance.

And your code will change to

```
for url in urls:
    driver = TorBrowserDriver(PATH_OF_TOR_DRIVER)
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(DELAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except :
        print("error occured, closing the connection.")
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: apologies for being unclear, but the issue is in `driver.get(url)`. after executing this line it downloads a file, and execution gets stuck and does not proceed further. I am not getting any exception.(try/except block is there to handle any malformed url )

Comment: we didn't provide all the code - so we cannot just guess. Maybe the file is downloading, maybe the process gets hanged etc.